# Not able to run simple hello world module in nginx server

Tags: nginx

I am trying to implement a simple Hello World module in nginx server. Below are some details about the nginx server and the module i am using:

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/nginx# nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.4.1
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --with-pcre-jit --with-debug --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-ipv6 --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.4.1/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.4.1/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.4.1/debian/modules/nginx-echo --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.4.1/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.4.1/debian/modules/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module
```

I am using the hello world module from this link: [hello world module](http://lumux.co.uk/2012/03/23/my-first-nginx-module/)

I haven't done any kind of changes to it.
Then i used `./configure --add-module=/home/user/module/nginx_module`. Where `nginx_module` directory contains the `config` file and `ngx_http_hello_world_module.c` file.

```
root@ubuntu:/home/user/Downloads/nginx-1.4.4# ./configure --add-module=/home/user/module/nginx_module

configuring additional modules
adding module in /home/user/module/nginx_module
 + ngx_http_hello_world_module was configured

nginx path prefix: "/usr/local/nginx"
  nginx binary file: "/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx"
  nginx configuration prefix: "/usr/local/nginx/conf"
  nginx configuration file: "/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf"
  nginx pid file: "/usr/local/nginx/logs/nginx.pid"
  nginx error log file: "/usr/local/nginx/logs/error.log"
  nginx http access log file: "/usr/local/nginx/logs/access.log"
  nginx http client request body temporary files: "client_body_temp"
  nginx http proxy temporary files: "proxy_temp"
  nginx http fastcgi temporary files: "fastcgi_temp"
  nginx http uwsgi temporary files: "uwsgi_temp"
  nginx http scgi temporary files: "scgi_temp"
```

Then `make`

```
cc -c -pipe  -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused-parameter -Werror -g   -I src/core -I src/event -I src/event/modules -I src/os/unix -I objs -I src/http -I src/http/modules -I src/mail \
        -o objs/addon/nginx_module/ngx_http_hello_world_module.o \
        /home/user/module/nginx_module/ngx_http_hello_world_module.c

objs/addon/nginx_module/ngx_http_hello_world_module.o \
    objs/ngx_modules.o \
```

and `make install`. After doing this, I added the below code to `/usr/nginx/nginx.conf file`:

```
server {
                listen 80;
                server_name localhost;

                location = /hello_world {
                        hello_world;
                        hello_world_string "Sample Message";
                }
       }
```

Then after reloading the config file with the command gives the following error:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/user# nginx -s reload
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "hello_world" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:79
```

Can anyone tell me where I am doing the wrong step?

**Update:** **1)** `whereis nginx` gives the the below path:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/user/Downloads/nginx-1.4.4# whereis nginx
nginx: /usr/sbin/nginx /etc/nginx /usr/local/nginx /usr/share/nginx /usr/share/man/man1/nginx.1.gz
```

Comment: Are you sure you are running the nginx you just compiled at /usr/local/nginx and not the old one from /usr/sbin/nginx?

Comment: @etagenklo Ty for replying.... I used to run `#service nginx start` and `#service nginx stop` for starting and stopping the server. I really don't know which 'nginx' server it is running.... will let you know tomorrow...

Comment: @etagenklo: You are correct. `#which nginx` gives me the path `/usr/sbin/nginx`. can you tell me how to change this path to `/usr/local/nginx`.

Comment: Right now I can run the hello world module by using `#/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx` but i want to change the path so that i can normally use it with the command `#service nginx start`

Comment: I'd suggest to edit the paths in your startscript at /etc/init.d/nginx. Best thing would be to copy your startscript to /etc/init.d/nginx_new first and edit this one. This way, you will have startscripts for the old and the new nginx.

Comment: This is the `PATH` and the `DAEMON` variable in the `/etc/init.d/nginx`

`PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON=/usr/sbin/nginx
NAME=nginx
DESC=nginx`.

I changed it to:
`PATH=/usr/local/nginx:/usr/local/nginx/sbin
DAEMON=/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx
NAME=nginx
DESC=nginx`
But it is saying `root@ubuntu:/etc/init.d# service nginx start
/etc/init.d/nginx: 31: awk: not found`

Comment: Do not remove the other parts of your PATH, otherwise the other binaries needed (e.g. `awk`) will not be found.